# Famo.us Scrollview setPosition with transition

Tags: famo.us

Trying to very simply scroll a famous `Scrollview` to a pixel position with a transition. It looks like `Scrollview`'s `setPosition` function will set the scroll position in pixels (right?). But how do I add a transition to this.

My first thought was to use a `Transitionable` to move from the scrollview's `getPosition` to the end position, but this led to another question: How do I watch a transitionable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right now the famous Scrollview does not support setting the position with any kind of transition.  There are a number of things you can do to simulate the transition, such as dividing the total difference in position by the length of the transition and then adding that value to the position every render frame.  This would give the illusion of a transition.

Comment: That was my first thought too. What is the best (famo.us) way of doing that, though? I could roll my own tween function, but it seems like this is exactly what famo.us would be great at; either with a Transitionable or physics.

Comment: This is something I am actively thinking about, so you might want to watch my adapted [ScrollView](https://github.com/jd-carroll/focus-scroll-view).  Also you might want to check out [flex-scrollview](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex) and see if there is any support there.